# Remove duplicates in nested objects of object

Tags: javascript, lodash

Trying to parse some network descriptions from devices, hitting a problem where a description could be duplicate across types. This causes errors further down the road in code. What is the best choice with lodash or javascript to compare each nested object and remove duplicates until they don't exist in the arrays. The goal is that string 1 - 111 would be removed until it only exists in one object.

```js
const data = {
    "hostname": {
        "typeA": [
            "string 1 - 111",
            "string 2 - 222",
            "string 3 - 333"
        ],
        "typeB": [
            "string 1 - 111",
            "string 4 - 444",
            "string 5 - 555"
        ],
        "typeC": [
            "string 1 - 111",
            "string 6 - 666"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output and also share the code which you have attempted?

Comment: I was using a temp array to house the values but was only making it two nested arrays deep. anything beyond two nested arrays failed. filter() was what I was needing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to iterate over each type array and filter based on a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of previously seen values. Here mutating `data` in place using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to both populate the `Set` and to return the filtered array.

```js
const data = {
  hostname: {
    typeA: ['string 1 - 111', 'string 2 - 222', 'string 3 - 333'],
    typeB: ['string 1 - 111', 'string 4 - 444', 'string 5 - 555'],
    typeC: ['string 1 - 111', 'string 6 - 666'],
  },
};

const seen = new Set();

for (const key of Object.keys(data.hostname)) {
  data.hostname[key] = data.hostname[key].filter((s) => {
    const _seen = seen.has(s);
    seen.add(s);

    return !_seen;
  });
}

console.log(data);
```